# How to avoid duplication of models when using FastAPI in a microservice architecture?

Tags: python, rest, kubernetes, backend, fastapi

I'm implementing a microservice with several backends all using FastAPI. The gateway is also using the same framework.

I want to avoid the duplication of `pydantic` models across the gateway and the services. For example, I have an endpoint on the `campaign` service that handles CRUD operations with a database with the with the following code.

Create campaign endpoint on `campaign` CRUD service:

```py
@router.post("", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_campaign(campaign: CreateCampaign = Depends(create_campaign)):
    print("created campaign")
    return jsonable_encoder(campaign)
```

CreateCampaign model:

```py
class CreateCampaign(BaseModel):
    name: str
```

Create campaign endpoint on `gateway` service for passing the request back to the `campaign` service:

```py
@router.post('')
async def create_campaign(campaign: CreateCampaign):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        resp = await client.post("http://pfi-service/campaign", data=json.dumps(jsonable_encoder(campaign)))
        print(resp.content)
        return resp.json()
```

These 2 endpoints share the same models for the request and response body.

I'm using Kubernetes for the deployment of the gateway and the services.

Currently, I'm just copying the model definitions over from the services to the gateway as importing them from a common module will not work when the services are deployed on their own.

How should I implement this?

**EDIT:**
I found a similar question on the Software Engineering StackExchange and they advised **against** doing this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366237. I will consider the question to be answered but will leave it open for specific implementation.

THANKS!

Comment: Can you use a layer like OpenAPI or GraphQL to define a schema for the over-the-wire messages?  If you do, can you generate the model objects?  That would save you from actually duplicating the code, and give you a well-defined path if you do need to change the schema in the future.  (In Kubernetes especially, it is all but guaranteed that you'll be running "old" and "new" versions of your code concurrently during an upgrade.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the idea! I'll look into implementing this later down the road. For my own and others reference, here's a library to convert OpenAPI specs into pydantic models: https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator.